# How do you use openshiftBuild in a jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline-as-code set up, but my project files from the 'Gradle Build' stage aren't being passed along through the pipeline, and I end up with an *Error: Could not find or load main class App* message in the final container.

How do you give the project files to the *openshiftBuild* command inside of the 'Build Image' stage?

```
node('gradle'){
    stage('SCM Checkout'){
        // Clone git repo.
    }

    stage('Gradle Build'){
        dir('/tmp/workspace/myproject/myproject-fproj/javaDemo'){
        sh 'gradle build'
        }
    }

    stage('Build Image'){
        openshiftBuild(buildConfig: 'javademo', showBuildLogs: 'true')
    }

    stage('Test Container Availability'){
        openshiftVerifyBuild(buildConfig: 'javademo')
    }

    stage('Deploy Application'){
        openshiftDeploy(deploymentConfig: 'javademo')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`openshiftBuild` doesn't have an argument to specify which directory to build from because it pulls the build configuration set up for that app. Here's the page that specifies the arguments for each of the Openshift plugin commands: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/openshift-pipeline/

To solve this problem, I defined these variables in the Jenkinsfile:

```
String ocpApiServer = env.OCP_API_SERVER ? "${env.OCP_API_SERVER}" : "https://openshift.default.svc.cluster.local"

env.TOKEN = readFile('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token').trim()

env.OC_CMD = "oc --request-timeout='0' --token=${env.TOKEN} --server=${ocpApiServer} --certificate-authority=/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt"
```

Then in my 'Build Image' stage I used:

```
sh "${env.OC_CMD} start-build javademo --from-dir=build/libs --wait=true --follow=true || exit 1"
```

This allowed me to pass the files I wanted from the libs directory to the s2i image.